# Book about the mystic meaning of Yom Kippur?

Tags: jewish-books, mysticism-kabbalah, yom-kippur

I’m trying to find a book about the mystic meaning for Yom Kippur, I believe the books title is something honey.

Comment: https://www.sefer.org.il/items/3729951-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A7-%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A9-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A7-%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A9

Comment: Sorry, but I do not read Hebrew

Comment: What is mystic meaning. Can you explain?

Comment: Someone wrote a book about the kabbalistic meaning of Yom Kippur, I’m trying to find the title, it’s a very short book with honey in the title I believe

Answer (score 1):

Try out "The Month of Tishrei: A Time of Rebirth and Upward Movement", by Reb Dovber Pinson.

Comment: He's looking for a specific book, just doesn't remember the title.

Comment: Thank you, will look it up

Answer (score 0):

The book is called Yearos Dvash, by Rabbi Yonatan Eybeschütz